# Pink Weed Flower Identification

Tags: identification

This weed grew itself out of nowhere but have this beautiful flower.

[image: Small pink 5-petalled flower]

It is very small like a penny sized flower. Can anyone please identify it ?

I want to know its name so that I can find how I can save its seeds for next spring.

*Edit

More pictures from today, 17th March, 2022.

[image: small pink flower]

[image: small pink flower]

Comment: Hi Ammar, and welcome. Could you le us know where you saw this plant? Different places have very different climates and very different wild species.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Its in the city of Karachi, Pakistan. On 14th March. I have included pictures from today.

Answer (score 1):

**Bingo!!** 
That weed is actually a flowering perennial and annual plant.

This is a species of [Phlox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlox), most probabaly *Phlox drummondii* (Flox Drum-on-dye) aka *Annual Phlox*.

They are easy-care, low-maintenance, fairly drought tolerant . These ornamental plants are very easy to grow from seed. Once established, your plants may go native and reseed themselves.

Know more about these plants from [these](https://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=phdr) web [sites](https://www.thespruce.com/growing-phlox-drummondii-5076303).
You can  checkout the seed collection procedures in youtube videos.

Answer (score 0):

That actually looks very much like Epilobium hirsutum to me, or hairy willow herb. There are two things to check. Is it a fairly tall plant and is it growing somewhere damp or near water? According to Wikipedia, “The native range of the species includes North Africa, most of Europe up to southern Sweden, and parts of Asia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilobium_hirsutum#Distribution